# how to calculate arccos() in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to calculate `arccos()` in a bash script.
gawk can calculate `cos(theta)` and `sin(theta)`
how to calculate `arccos()` in linux ?

Comment: *Why* do you want to calculate arccos? Why do you want to use bash for this?

Comment: to keep calculation speed. The script is written in bash entirely. is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using command line tool `bc` and refer to [Advantage Bash](http://advantage-bash.blogspot.com/2012/12/trignometry-calculator.html), arccosine function is shown as below while `$1` is first argument for `arccos()` function.

```
arccos ()
{
    scale=3
    if (( $(echo "$1 == 0" | bc -l) )); then
        echo "a(1)*2" | bc -l
    elif (( $(echo "(-1 <= $1) && ($1 < 0)" | bc -l) )); then
        echo "scale=${scale}; a(1)*4 - a(sqrt((1/($1^2))-1))" | bc -l
    elif (( $(echo "(0 < $1) && ($1 <= 1)" | bc -l) )); then
        echo "scale=${scale}; a(sqrt((1/($1^2))-1))" | bc -l
    else
        echo "input out of range"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: thanks @Cristian Ciupitu for the edition for only radian answer and include negative input.

Answer (score 8):

You can do what you want by calling out to, perl for example:

```
acos_05=`perl -E 'use Math::Trig; say acos(0.5)'`
```

However, as michas pointed out, why would you want to do that in bash? If you need to do anything more than adding and multiplying numbers, bash is just not the tool for the job. It never was designed to do that, it lacks builtin functions for it, and most of all, its quoting behavior (treating everything as string) makes it a pain to get anything done in practice.

I'd recommend any programming language (not shell scripting language) of your choice: Python, Ruby, Tcl, Perl, ...; all of them are better languages than bash.